# Reading XML config file on run time in a phone gap / cordova application

Tags: android, angularjs, xml, cordova, phonegap-build

I was trying to read the xml config file on a phonegap application on runtime: While running on the emulator the config.xml is in the root directory and easily accessable with a get instruction, i can't figure where on the phone this file is stored.

This is the code for reading the XML for retrieving some data directly (for example you can retrieve the version) using angular JS, i just share for anyone may need.

```
   getXmlConfig: function (path) {
            var defer = $q.defer();
            if (!navigator.platform.match(/Win32|Mac/i)) {
                configfilepath = path;

            }
            else {
                configfilepath = "config.xml";
            }
            getXmlData(configfilepath).success(function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    var parser = new DOMParser();
                    var doc = parser.parseFromString(data, "application/xml");
                    var tagXml = doc.getElementsByTagName("widget");
                    dataretrieved = tagXml[0].getAttribute('version');
                    defer.resolve(dataretrieved);
                });
            return defer.promise;
        }
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

@Alex,
the Cordova/Phonegap file named `config.xml` is not available once you App has been bundled into an APK(Android) or IPA(iOS). One of the purposes of Cordova/Phonegap is to relieve the programmer from such details.

I am told, if you download you your APK, and change the file name extension to `.zip` you will see there is NO `config.xml` in the bundle; in it's place you will find `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Comment: no, the config.xml is inside the APK, but it's outside the www folder, so you can't get it using javascript

Comment: @jcesarmobile, I was curious. So I downloaded one of my APKs. There is no `config.xml`. There is an `AndroidManifest.xml` in the root directory of the bundle.

Comment: It's on ```res/xml/```

Comment: Thanks for the insight. Mine must have been corrupted. I looked at config.xml in the gedit (local GUI on linux) and it looks compressed - or something else. Rather than bug you on this, I'd appreciate any pointers you might have. TIA Jesse

Answer (score 0):

Ok so if it's impossbile with javascript, it can be read by the file plugin!

There is a list of possibile path where the config file is stored, but can't find anything in documentation about.

Android File System Layout

Device Path cordova.file.*

***file:///android_asset/***    applicationDirectory

***/data/data//***  applicationStorageDirectory

***cache*** cacheDirectory

***files*** dataDirectory

***Documents***     documents

***sdcard/***   externalRootDirectory

***Android/data//***    externalApplicationStorageDirectory

***cache*** externalCacheDirectory

***files*** externalDataDirectory